# How to integrate webrtc android native library on xamarin android project?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, webrtc

I'm facing problem on integrating the latest WebRTC library for Android on my Xamarin Android application, using the latest version: `1.0.24139` from [here](https://bintray.com/google/webrtc/google-webrtc)

I've followed the instruction from [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/).

I've also changed `Transforms->Metadata.xml` as follows:

```
<metadata>
    <!--Fix incorrect Visibility-->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']/class[@name='CameraCapturer']" name="visibility">public</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']/class[@name='GlGenericDrawer']" name="visibility">public</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']/class[@name='WrappedNativeVideoDecoder']" name="visibility">public</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']/class[@name='WrappedNativeVideoEncoder']" name="visibility">public</attr>

   <!-- Rename StatusReport.Value.Value to StatusReport.Value.Val to avoid conflict -->
   <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']/class[@name='StatsReport.Value']/field[@name='value']" name="name">val</attr>

   <!--.NET namespace names-->
   <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.webrtc']" name="managedName">WebRTC</attr>
</metadata>
```

Xamarin Android binding project successfully built and generated `dll`.

But when I reference this project to my Xamarin android project, it throws an exception during build as the screenshot below:

[image]

But I've able to build successfully with the older version: `1.0.19742`

Can Anyone help, please? I want to build a project with the latest WebRTC library for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I try to do the same thing as you. Try two things :

- Set the min Android SDK to 26 as mentioned in the error.
- Put `<AndroidEnableDesugar>true</AndroidEnableDesugar>` in your Android project file.